# How to get a one-dimensional scalar array as a doctrine dql query result?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I want to get an array of values from the id column of the Auction table.
If this was a raw SQL I would write:

```
SELECT id FROM auction
```

But when I do this in Doctrine and execute:

```
$em->createQuery("SELECT a.id FROM Auction a")->getScalarResult();
```

I get an array like this:

```
array(
    array('id' => 1),
    array('id' => 2),
)
```

Instead, i'd like to get an array like this:

```
array(
    1,
    2
)
```

How can I do that using Doctrine?

Answer (score 210, accepted):

#### PHP < 5.5

You can use `array_map`, and since you only have on item per array, you can elegantly use 
`'current'` as callback, instead of writing a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11685062/2943194).

```
$result = $em->createQuery("SELECT a.id FROM Auction a")->getScalarResult();
$ids = array_map('current', $result);
```

> See [Petr Sobotka's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22424012/133717) for additional info regarding memory usage.

#### PHP >= 5.5

As [jcbwlkr's answered below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26061738/133717), the recommended way it to use `array_column`.

Comment: getScalarResult() will give you strings - use getArrayResult() if you want integers

Comment: so! is array_column() better at memory management or is it the foreach way, what shoud we do?

Answer (score 179):

As of PHP 5.5 you can use [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to solve this

```
$result = $em->createQuery("SELECT a.id FROM Auction a")->getScalarResult();
$ids = array_column($result, "id");
```

Answer (score 105):

A better solution is to use `PDO:FETCH_COLUMN` . To do so you need a custom hydrator:

```
//MyProject/Hydrators/ColumnHydrator.php
namespace DoctrineExtensions\Hydrators\Mysql;

use Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\AbstractHydrator, PDO;

class ColumnHydrator extends AbstractHydrator
{
    protected function hydrateAllData()
    {
        return $this->_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    }
}
```

Add it to Doctrine:

```
$em->getConfiguration()->addCustomHydrationMode('COLUMN_HYDRATOR', 'MyProject\Hydrators\ColumnHydrator');
```

And you can use it like this:

```
$em->createQuery("SELECT a.id FROM Auction a")->getResult("COLUMN_HYDRATOR");
```

More info:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#custom-hydration-modes

Comment: I've modified this so it supports indexBy https://gist.github.com/ostrolucky/f9f1e0b271357573fde55b7a2ba91a32

Answer (score 18):

Ascarius' answer is elegant, but beware of memory usage! `array_map()` creates a copy of passed array and effectively doubles memory usage. If you work with hundreds of thousands of array items this can become an issue. Since PHP 5.4 call-time pass by reference has been removed so you cannot do

```
// note the ampersand
$ids = array_map('current', &$result);
```

In that case you can go with obvious

```
$ids = array();
foreach($result as $item) {
  $ids[] = $item['id'];
}
```

Comment: That seemed a bit counter-intuitive, since our goal is to "almost copy" the array in both cases. I had to test it myself to be convinced it is actually true: https://gist.github.com/PowerKiKi/9571aea8fa8d6160955f

Answer (score 18):

#### Since doctrine/orm 2.10.0 there is a built-in solution for this:

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery;

$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT a.id FROM Auction a");
return $query->getSingleColumnResult();
// Same as:
return $query->getResult(AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_SCALAR_COLUMN);
```

Docs: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.10/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#scalar-column-hydration

Comment: When using query builder, I had to define the column that I wanted to have returned:
```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');

// ... Build the query

$resultMapping = new Query\ResultSetMapping();
$resultMapping->addScalarResult('id', 'id', 'integer');

return $query->getQuery()>setResultSetMapping($resultMapping)->getSingleColumnResult();
```

Answer (score 4):

I think it's impossible in Doctrine.
Just transform result array into the data structure you want using PHP:

```
$transform = function($item) {
    return $item['id'];
};
$result = array_map($transform, $em->createQuery("SELECT a.id FROM Auction a")->getScalarResult());
```