# (Symfony) Doctrine ORM findAll: too much information

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I was wondering if it is possible to modify `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Foo')->findAll()`, so that I only get the *IDs* of the related entities. Because Foo is related to 'one User' and 'multiple Groups', I always get the 'whole User object' and 'ALL Group objects' in the result, which makes the result very unclear. So, is it possible to only print the IDs of the related objects?

I hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Comment: In this case you should use DQL instead of built-in repository methods.

Answer (score 5):

You don’t have to retrieve the full entities, you can as well select only the fields you need. Instead of an entity list, you will get a list of plain arrays, where each array contains the selected fields.

```
$ids = $em->createQueryBuilder() // $em is your entity manager
    ->select("foo.id")
    ->from("AppBundle:Foo", "foo")
    ->getQuery()->getResult();

$ids = array_map("current", $ids);
```

Note: The last line is optional, it will “flatten” your array when you select only one field.

Comment: In addition to this solution I'd suggest to do `getResult(AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_SCALAR)`. It makes the last line of the code unnecessary as soon as Doctrine will make the result of `getResult` an array

Comment: @Stepashka Maybe you can explain why you suggest this and what this line exactly does? Only suggesting things without any explanation won't help anybody.

Comment: @lxg If certain associations are marked as `fetch="EAGER"` this might still lead to unnecessary joins right? Or not?

Comment: @Stepashka: Unfortunately, `AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_SCALAR` doesn’t do what you think it does. You still get an array of arrays with one value each. This is a known problem, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657835/how-to-get-a-one-dimensional-scalar-array-as-a-doctrine-dql-query-result

Comment: @Wilt: I don’t know for sure, but don’t think so. If it did, I would consider it to be a bug in Doctrine.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to write your own custom query:

```
$query = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->createNativeQuery('SELECT id FROM foo'); 
$foos= $query->getResult();
```

the above should work
see here for more info http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html

Comment: Native queries are a bad suggestion as they circumvent the DBAL and bind your application to a specific DB product. Native queries are always your last resort, only to be used if everything else fails.

Comment: Also, what’s the point of `WHERE 1=1`? This only makes sense in crappy applications which extend the SQL statement through obscure filters. (*cough* … WordPress … *cough*)

Comment: It's to say select all... I'm sorry I use doctrine so much I rarely write sql queries. And since he is not putting any external inputs from the user into this, I don't see why this would be any less secure...

Comment: I didn’t say that `WHERE 1=1` is insecure, it’s just nonsense. `SELECT id FROM Foo` would be sufficient. Applications like WordPress add `WHERE 1=1` so you can extend the query through filters without knowing the original query (e.g. `$sql .= " AND field = 'value'"`).

Comment: Does Wordpress really do that? Another good reason to never use Wordpress.

Comment: I never used wordpress. Just for the record.

Comment: @Wilt: Just checked, they seem to have removed it recently, you can still see it in not-too-old branches. https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.6-branch/wp-includes/query.php#L3550 (Haven’t used WP for some years now, but when I had to, it made my eyes bleed.) Update: Just checked out the latest WP sources, and still found some results for `grep -r 'WHERE 1=1'`.

Comment: *"it made my eyes bleed"* 