# Get array of values using Doctrine

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using Symfony2 and Doctrine to get an array of values from the database. I want a list of values from one field of the database table.

I'm using the following code:

```
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('ad')
        ->select('ad.extId')
        ->where('ad.extId is not NULL')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();
```

It returns the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [extId] => 3038
        )
)
```

I would like to revieve the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3038
)
```

Any one an idee to get this direct from Doctrine without an extra foreach loop?

Comment: this would be it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657835/how-to-get-a-one-dimensional-scalar-array-as-a-doctrine-dql-query-result/11685062#11685062 or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657835/how-to-get-a-one-dimensional-scalar-array-as-a-doctrine-dql-query-result/11685062#11685062

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without custom hydrator, I don't think it is possible out of the box. However, you could do this (similar to `foreach`):

```
$arr = $this->createQueryBuilder('ad')
        ->select('ad.extId')
        ->where('ad.extId is not NULL')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();

return array_map(function($a){ return $a['extId']; }, $arr);
```

Comment: For PHP5.5+ there's `array_column()` function which may be used instead of `array_map` here. `array_map($arr, 'extId');` is simpler and actually has better performance.

Comment: Sweet :) And you meant `array_column($arr, 'extId')` ;)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. :D