# Turn object to an array and get its values

Tags: php, symfony4

`foreach ($this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Personal::class)->findBy(array('uid' => $id)) as $object) {`

In my code `$object` returns an object with the values and columns from my database. I would like to convert that object to an array. I can do this with `$array = (array) $object;`.

If I use `var_export($array)`, this will be the output:

```
array (
  '' . "\0" . 'App\\Entity\\Personal' . "\0" . 'id' => 5,
  '' . "\0" . 'App\\Entity\\Personal' . "\0" . 'uid' => 43,
  '' . "\0" . 'App\\Entity\\Personal' . "\0" . 'city' => 'Zurich',
)
```

I would like to get the value of city with `$array['city']` but "city" is an undefined index. What's the best way to get the value?

Comment: The proper way would be to get the value using `$object->getCity()` given that you have proper getters and setters in the `Personal` entity.

Comment: Can you show your Personal entity class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using  `findBy`, write a doctrine custom query then set the result as Array. As here : [Symfony 4, doctrine, getResult and getArrayResult and getScalarResult return same structure results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48044986/symfony-4-doctrine-getresult-and-getarrayresult-and-getscalarresult-return-sam?rq=1)