# Doctrine return only one parameter of the related entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Entity `TestEntity` has parameter which relates to another entity called `TestEntityRelated`. This entity `TestEntityRelated` has only one integer parameter - `price`. I want this `price` parameter to be returned as single parameter instead of the whole `invalidPrice` object.

`TestEntity` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned":true})
 */
 private $id;

 /**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=TestEntityRelated::class, mappedBy="offer", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $price;
```

`TestEntityRelated` entity:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=TestEntity::class, inversedBy="price")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned":true})
 */
private $price;
```

For example if I get the `Entity` object it should contain this:

```
-price: 1
```

instead of:

```
-price: App\Entity\TestEntityRelated {#1551
-entity: App\Entity\Entity {#1532}
-price: 1
}
```

Comment: If you've got a OneToOne relationship where one side only contains a single property, it sounds like the "correct" answer would be to move the property to the main Offer entity itself. If that's not possible, you can just add a getter to the Offer entity that returns `$this->invalidPrice->hasInvalidPrice` as an integer, and the rest of your application doesn't need to know that another object was involved at all.

Comment: Yes, moving that property to the main Offer entity is not possible, because it has to be on different database table. And indeed I have the hasInvalidPrice property getter, but if I get the whole Offer object it automatically returns full invalidPrice object as a property too.

Comment: Sure, and I'm not sure there's a way around that in Doctrine. But why is that causing a problem? The invalidPrice object is private - the rest of your application can't access it. I would just change the hasInvalidPrice property getter to return the related property instead (or I guess ideally a boolean?), and ignore what's happening underneath. You're working around an issue with the schema that you can't change, but the only place in your code that needs to know about that is the Offer entity. Everything else will look correct.

Comment: I just thought that it may be more cleaner way to get the data in Doctrine way. I don't need the whole object if it has only one property.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a one-dimensional scalar array as a doctrine dql query result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657835/how-to-get-a-one-dimensional-scalar-array-as-a-doctrine-dql-query-result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently solved this by editing the `getPrice` getter:

```
public function getPrice(): ?int
{
    return $this->price ? $this->price->getPrice(): null;
}
```

I return the `price` property instead of the whole `price` object.